# Php Video Upload error

Tags: php, mysql, video, file-upload

I am trying to upload a video and save the link to the database. I have wrote the code but I am getting this error. Doe someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
$file = "http://127.0.0.1/webapp/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded/$name";

mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO oefeningen (`Id`, `Fname`, `Lname`, `namevideo`, `video`, `expl`)
    VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', ,'$namevideo', '$file','$expl')
") or die (mysql_error());
```

thx!

The error i am getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test.mov', 'http://127.0.0.1/webapp/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploade' at line 2
```

Comment: That short snippet of your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Database_Cheat_Sheet) and [remote execution](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#File_uploads) of code. So you should really read up on security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lname', ,'$namevideo',
```

You have an extra comma so it should be

```
$lname', '$namevideo',
```

Comment: Thx that was the fastest answer ever!!

Comment: Tick the above answer as correct and Vote it up.. Thanks..